# how to get the number and the name of the following sibilings

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath, sax

is there any way in xpath to count the following sibling of a tag and get the siblings name as well??

i tried the following to count the following sibilings:

```
Expression xpath2 = dog.addXPath("count(//node[@lat='53.0337395']
[@lon='8.8489255']/following-sibling)");
```

but it returns 0 and i expected to get as there are three following elements:

```
<tag k="maxspeed" v="30"/>  
<tag k="maxspeed:zone" v="yes"/>
<ele k="maxspeed:zone" v="60"/>
```

and i do not know how to get the name of the following sibilings of a node.

**xml**:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<osm>
<node id="25779111" lat="53.0334062" lon="8.8461545"/>
<node id="25779112" lat="53.0338904" lon="8.846314"/>
<node id="25779119" lat="53.0337395" lon="8.8489255"/>
<tag k="maxspeed" v="30"/>
<tag k="maxspeed:zone" v="yes"/>
<ele k="maxspeed:zone" v="60"/>
<node id="25779114" lat="53.334062" lon="8.841545"/>
<node id="25779117" lat="53.338904" lon="8.84614"/>
<node id="25779110" lat="53.33795" lon="8.489255"/>
<tag k="maxspeed" v="32"/>
<tag k="maxspeed:zone" v="no"/>
</osm>
```

Comment: if the pointed node will be in the first set you can count `tag[following::node]` but it will give zero if take node from the seconf set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count *the first set of siblings of  which is called tag.*

```
count(//node[@lat='53.0337395' and @lon='8.8489255']/following-sibling::tag[following-sibling::node])
```

But it will work if the pointed node is in the first set. But it will give zero if take node from the second set because there is no `following-sibling::node` for them

Answer (score 2):

You can use `following-sibling::node()` to find all kind of nodes (element nodes, comment nodes, text nodes, processing instruction nodes) on the following-sibling axis or `following-sibling::*` to find all elements on that axis or `following-sibling::tag` to find all `tag` elements on that axis.

Comment: i tried following-sibling::tag and according to the posted xml file, it returned 4 which is equal to the whole elements names tag, is there any way to count only the first two elemets named tag in the xml file?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. If you know your are looking for two elements, why would you need to count them? The following-sibling axis contains all following sibling nodes, as explained, you can filter on different types of nodes, on element names. You can also add predicates, like in any XPath expression e.g. `following-sibling::tag[position() < 3]` would give you the first two `tag` elements on the following-sibling axis.

Comment: i mean, without knowing that there are 2 elements called tag, how can i count the first set of siblings of <node> which is called tag, which is according to the xml file posted, equals 2

Comment: The `following-sibling` axis does not stop just because there is an element of the same name so `following-sibling::tag` in your posted sample would select four `tag` elements `<tag k="maxspeed" v="30"/>`, `<tag k="maxspeed:zone" v="yes"/>`, `<tag k="maxspeed" v="32"/>` and `<tag k="maxspeed:zone" v="no"/>`. As for selecting only the first two of those four, it is not clear which criteria you want to apply to select them. Or perhaps it will be easier to use some grouping approach in XSLT or XQuery.